options for nominating a charity from a donor-advised fund
This question is about the mechanics of a donor-advised fund (DAF). If I set one up, how can I nominate a charity? In particular, can I get a "debit card number" so that I can directly send the funds to a charity through their online giving portal, for example?
Or am I going to need the DAF to essentially send checks to the charity (and need the mailing address of every charity I wish to donate to as a result)?
I put "debit card number" in quotes because obviously it wouldn't be a real debit card since the money would no longer be mine, but what I'm hoping is that I could find a DAF that will give me a number so that I can easily connect it with the charities.

Generally, you just give the DAF fund the contact info for the charity (if it isn't already in their database). They then work with the charity to find the best way to transfer the funds -- EFT if they can, check in the mail otherwise. You aren't involved in any of those details.
